# Create rows of dynamic dropdowns based on value of another dropdown in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select and I want to create n rows of two dropdowns such that the options in one drop down is dependent on the value selected in the other dropdown of the same row. Say I have the following values:

```
options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
sub_options = { 'A' : [1,2,3],
                'B' : [4,5,6],
                'C' : [7,8,9],
                'D' : [10,11,12] }
```

For eg. when I select option `A` in the first drop down, the second drop down has options `1,2,3`.

There can be n number of rows. I hope my question is understandable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pnjq1t

```
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        options: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
        sub_options: {
          A: [1, 2, 3],
          B: [4, 5, 6],
          C: [7, 8, 9],
          D: [10, 11, 12]
        },
        selectedSubOptions: []
      };
  }

  onOptionChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      selectedSubOptions: this.state.sub_options[event.target.value]
    });    
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Options:
        <select onChange={this.onOptionChange}>
          <option value="">Please select</option>
          {this.state.options.map(item => (
            <option value={item} key={item}>
              {item}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <br />
        Sub Options:
        <select>
          <option value="">Please select</option>
          {this.state.selectedSubOptions.map(item => (
            <option value={item} key={item}>
              {item}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I get it for having two dropdowns. What if I need multiple dropdowns? I mean now it has one row of two dropdowns. What if I want about 5 (can be a variable number) rows of such dropdowns. How do I frame my code then?

Comment: @Crazzay1903 Multiple dropdown or multiple row with 2 dropdowns. Make sure what you need.

Comment: Multiple row with 2 dropdowns. Sorry if I have been unclear

Comment: @Crazzay1903 Refer the same stackblitz link. I have modified the answer over there. You can create n number of rows. Just modify the array length. You can also do with a number you pass. For that pass a number, create a dummy array of that and iterate over that.

Comment: Understood! Thanks a lot. I was banging my head finding a solution to this.

Comment: A pleasure to help you..!!

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing the library i would say something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Select, { OptionsType } from 'react-select'

const options: OptionsType<any> = [
  { value: 'A', label: 'A' },
  { value: 'B', label: 'B' },
  { value: 'C', label: 'C' }
]

const subOptions: { [key: string]: OptionsType<any> } = {
  A: [
    { value: '1', label: '1' },
    { value: '2', label: '2' },
    { value: '3', label: '3' }
  ],
  B: [
    { value: '4', label: '4' },
    { value: '5', label: '5' },
    { value: '6', label: '6' }
  ],
  C: [
    { value: '7', label: '7' },
    { value: '8', label: '8' },
    { value: '9', label: '9' }
  ]
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<{ value: string; label: string }>(options[0])
  const [subValue, setSubValue] = useState<{ value: string; label: string }>(subOptions[value.value][0])

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={options}
        value={value}
        onChange={(value) => {
          setValue(value)
          setSubValue(subOptions[value.value][0])
        }}
      />
      <Select 
        options={subOptions[value.value]} 
        value={subValue} 
        onChange={(value) => 
          setSubValue(value)
        } 
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```